# Crop & upload image of big size using Jcrop

Tags: javascript, image-processing, crop, image-uploading, jcrop

I'm using Jcrop to crop and upload image. I'm using this tutorial and source code to develop my system

[html5-image-uploader-with-jcrop](http://www.script-tutorials.com/html5-image-uploader-with-jcrop/)

Now it can't handle images that are more than 250 KB. It gives an error as

> *You have selected too big file, please select a one smaller image file*

So I tried to change the **script.js**. On the **fileSelectHandler**  method, I tried to change this line

> if (oFile.size > 250* 1024)

with

> if (oFile.size > 2048 * 2048)

But it didn't work. I can't find any other option to change. Can anyone please tell me what I'm missing? How can I withdraw this size restrictions? I want to handle 2mb size image or at least of (1024*1024) pixels size image. Please help......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st changed the upload.php file. A line from

```
if (! $_FILES['image_file']['error'] && $_FILES['image_file']['size'] < 250 * 1024)
```

to

```
if (! $_FILES['image_file']['error'] && $_FILES['image_file']['size'] < 2048* 2048)
```

As I mentioned in the question, changed script.js. A line from

```
if (oFile.size > 250* 1024)
```

to

```
if (oFile.size > 2048 * 2048)
```

And lastly to be able to save the image in the cropping size rather not in some pre-defined size, I added an extra line of

```
$iHeight=(int)$_POST['h']; $iWidth=(int)$_POST['w'];
```

before this line

```
$vDstImg = @imagecreatetruecolor( $iWidth, $iHeight );
```

Then the image will be saved in exact same size as cropped in preview.